# ids_for_pages api return empty data while aim using page access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to call ids_for_pages but it always returns "data": [] and I am using page scope id and access token.
does anyone know why?

Comment: Are the app and the page(s) in question “owned” by the same business?

Comment: yes they are owned by the same business

Comment: In what way has the user in question interacted with the page? What mode/access level is your app currently in?

Comment: the user has a lot of comments and reactions on my page. and I have an advanced access level on many of the permissions.

Comment: ps the app was owned by another business and I was able to get ids_for_pages with the pages related to the previous business but when I changed the app business I can't get ids for pages for the pages related to the new business

Comment: Did that change of the app’s owning business fully go through yet, or is there maybe some stuff left to review/approve?

Comment: yes the change if fully approved and verified

Comment: Then I can only recommend you file a bug report and ask them to look into this. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only get ids_for_pages for people that started a conversation with your page. it will return empty data[] if the user commented or reacted only.